# SQL using a function to check existence of event over a user id?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table 'EVENTS' with a user column, and an 'event' column

| User | Event |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 1 | a |
| 1 | a |
| 1 | b |
| 2 | b |
| 2 | c |

In the above example, user 1 has never had event c appear for them. I want to do something like

```
WITH table_a as (
SELECT 
CASE WHEN EVENT = 'c' Then 'Y' ELSE 'n' end as event_occured,
user_id
FROM EVENTS)
```

and then get a result such as

| User | is_occured |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | n |
| 2 | y |

So I first tried to do it like such

```
SELECT DISTINCT USER,'y' is_occured FROM table_a WHERE event_occured='y'
UNION 
SELECT DISTINCT USER,'n' is_occured FROM table_a WHERE event_occured='n'
```

But this is obviously a bit clunky, and will be unmanageable, especially as more columns are added to the event table, and needed in the query. so next I tried to do it using a window function, but I'm not certain how to pull the values into only singular users, where I'm only looking for the existence.

```
SELECT user,
CASE WHEN ... over(partion by user)
FROM EVENTS
```

But I'm very confused how to procede or if this is even the right track

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are purely trying to get a `Y` or `N` onto these, you can do a simple `MAX` with a case expression:

```
select [User]
    , MAX(case when [Event] = 'c' then 'Y' else 'N' end) is_occurred
from [EVENTS]
group by [User]
```

If you wanted to avoid `group by`, you could do a window function:

```
select distinct [User]
    , MAX(case when [Event] = 'c' then 'Y' else 'N' end) over (partition by [User])
from [EVENTS]
```

If you wanted to have this as a function, you could parameterize the `[Event]` comparison and pass the user as well to something like:

```
select MAX(case when [Event] = @p_checked_event then 'Y' else 'N' end)
from [EVENTS]
where [User] = @p_checked_user
```

Return the results of that query, and call it like:

```
select distinct [User]
    , CheckEventOccurred([User], 'c')
from [EVENTS]
```